# Displaying different stuff to multiple Projectors.

Tags: directshow, projector

I want to connect multiple projector to single laptop, I found about **VGA Splitter** (http://www.kvmswitchtech.com/vga-splitter-350mhz-8-port-p46359.htm) which can use to connect multiple projectors to single PC.
But I don’t want to display whole screen in both Projectors, in short Projectors should display different stuff at same time.

For Example:-
 **Projector 1** can Display Power point Presentation and **Projector 2** can Display the running movie in player.

I got below set of Questions

1. Is there any Software available to perform this operation?
2. If I want to write my own application, Is Directshow (Provided by Microsoft ) is good one to start?
3. Is there any other VGA Programming language available?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Software available to perform this operation?

The primary question you are going to get here is how the projectors are connected to PC. The device might need specific integration and you're moving the item #2 below immediately. Otherwise it can be a sort of secondary monitor and you can extend your desktop over it, and then any full screen application running on the secondary monitor is going to be projected.

Perhaps, you will find more software choices going to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

> If I want to write my own application, Is Directshow (Provided by Microsoft ) is good one to start?

As mentioned above, the hardware might need you to use specific SDK from the vendor and this is your starting point. DirectShow is the API that covers multiple related tasks and might be of use here:

- it is capable to built media pipelines terminating at DirectShow-compatible video output device (the projector might be not might be not capable/compatible)
- it allows you to play media files into your application and otherwise control video/audio and integrate it into higher level software

DirectShow as API does not fully cover requested task, but it definitely relevant might be used in the in-house built Windows based app.

> Is there any other VGA Programming language available?

The "language" is not actually language and it is how particular device is integrated with PC. This is typically covered by hardware vendors who provide the hardware with accompanying development kits and samples.